# Process returned after detecting flashdrive(no errors and warnings)

Tags: c

I cannot understand why it could not write the data on the specified drive.

Calling functions for saving :

```
if(flashdrive()){
    savedata(accnumber,pin,amount);  process returning on this part 
    saveinfo();
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tPlease wait for a few seconds . . .");
    Sleep(2000);
    eject();
}
```

Saving data on drive

```
void savedata(char accnumber[25],char pin[6],int balance){
    LIST *p, *q;
    p = q = L;

    FILE *cardFile;
    encrypt();

    while(p != NULL){
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    if(p == NULL){
        cardFile = fopen("E:\\data.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(cardFile, "%s %s %d", q->accnumber, q->pin, q->balance);
        fclose(cardFile);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the drive is labeled `E`? Is the code you show your real code? Without any kind of error checking?

Comment: yup to all of your questions

Comment: Did you close your debug session (if any) before checking that the file was properly written ?

Comment: Consider checking the return value of fopen - it may have returned NULL in the case of an error.  If it does return NULL, you can call perror("") for more info.

Comment: Check fopen return value.

Comment: still nothing same outcome

Comment: Edit the post with the updated code if you've modified it.

Comment: Please take the [tour], learn [ask], and PLEASE provide a [example]. For example, what should we know about `L`?